# Can you make value_counts on a specific interval of characters with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a column "Names". If I do:

```
df['Names'].value_counts()
```

I get this:

```
Mr. Richard Vance       1
Mrs. Angela Bell        1
Mr. Stewart Randall     1
Mr. Andrew Ogden        1
Mrs. Maria Berry        1
                       ..
Mrs. Lillian Wallace    1
Mr. William Bailey      1
Mr. Paul Ball           1
Miss Pippa Bond         1
Miss Caroline Gray      1
```

It's ok... Thera are lots of DISTINCT names. But what I want is to do this value_counts() only for the first characters until it get's to the empty character (i.e. space that devides, for instance Miss or Mrs. from Lillian Wallace) So that the output would be, for example:

Mrs.     1000
Mr.      2000
Miss     2000

Just to know how many distinct variants there are in the column names so that, in a 2nd stage create another variable (namely gender) based on those variants.

Comment: `df['Names'].str.split().str.get(0).value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`value_counts(dropna=False)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on `str[0]` after a [**`str.split()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Mr. Richard Vance','Mrs. Angela Bell','Mr. Stewart Randall','Mr. Andrew Ogden','Mrs. Maria Berry','Mrs. Lillian Wallace','Mr. William Bailey','Mr. Paul Ball','Miss Pippa Bond','Miss Caroline Gray','']})

df.Names.str.split().str[0].value_counts(dropna=False)

#  Mr.     5
#  Mrs.    3
#  Miss    2
#  NaN     1
#  Name: Names, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the unique values and if there's always a space you can do this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Mr. Richard Vance',
'Mrs. Angela Bell',
'Mr. Stewart Randall',
'Mr. Andrew Ogden',
'Mrs. Maria Berry',
'Mrs. Lillian Wallace',
'Mr. William Bailey',
'Mr. Paul Ball',
'Miss Pippa Bond',
'Miss Caroline Gray'], columns=['names'])

df['names'].str.split(' ').str[0].unique().tolist()
```

Output is a list:

```
['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss']
```

Comment: Almost there... Just need a count on that list. You solution is better because, in my data set, I can see: ['Mr.', 'Miss', 'Mrs.', nan]. Now I need to know how many of these 4 possibilities there are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. You can use regex:

```
#Dataset

    Names
0   Mr. Richard Vance
1   Mrs. Angela Bell
2   Mr. Stewart Randall
3   Mr. Andrew Ogden
4   Mrs. Maria Berry
5   Mrs. Lillian Wallace

df['Names'].str.extract(r'(\w+\.\s)').value_counts()

#Output:

Mr.      3
Mrs.     3
```

Note : `(\w+\.\s)` will extract Mr. and Mrs. parts (or any title like Dr.) from the names